# Riverpod context.read() just returns the data type in the provider, so I can't update the value

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying to update the value inside `RecenterProvider`, which I'm creating with a `StateNotifierProvider`, but `read()` (the recommended method for updating values in callbacks) is just returning a `bool` instead of the actual provider.

Here's `RecenterProvider`

```
class RecenterProvider extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  RecenterProvider() : super(true);

  void toggle() => state = !state;
}
```

And here's my widget:

```
  final recenterProvider =
      StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<RecenterProvider, bool>(
          (_) => RecenterProvider());

...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      floatingActionButton: Consumer(
        builder: (context, watch, _) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.my_location,
              color: watch(recenterProvider)
                  ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                  : Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.color,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // This fails because read() returns a bool instead of a RecenterProvider
              context.read(recenterProvider).toggle();
            },
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          );
        },
      ),
...
```

I'm creating the `StateNotifierProvider` here instead of in main.dart because this provider is only being used in this widget and its children. I'm using a `Consumer` since only the `FloatingActionButton` uses this value, and the widget is stateful, so `ConsumerWidget` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than:

```dart
context.read(recenterProvider).toggle()
```

You need to do:

```dart
context.read(recenterProvider.notifier).toggle()
```

Comment: When do I need to call .notifier and when not?

Comment: flutter version 3.0.1, hey @remi, I am using context.read, but it shows BuildContext doesn't have a method read.
also by using provider.dart as follows
`context.read<dc.directorController.notifier>().joinCall(channelName: _chchannel);`
it is throwing error as
`"The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'T Function<T>()'.\nTry defining the operator '<'.",`
please help

Answer (score -1):

In my case I declared the context as nullable `BuildContext? context`. In this case you can access the `read`-method only via null check as follows: `context!.read(<provider>)`